# 이것 책상이다 - 이: noun or adjective

Tags: grammar, adjective, nouns

이것 책상이다 = This is a desk.

I have just consulted my dictionary and it said as follows.

이 = this (it may be a **noun** or **pronoun**)
 것 = thing (it is a noun)

So 이것 = this thing. 
I am wondering if Korean grammar is similar to English or not. As for English:

이 = this (it may be an **adjective** or **determiner**)
 것 = thing (it is a noun)

In Korean, can 이 also be considered as an adjective in that sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By itself, 이 is called a 관형사 - this is sometimes translated "undeclinable adjective", but it includes what are called determiners (like "this") in English as well as certain so-called adjectives, like 새 (new) that cannot be used as the predicate, and thus do not include any 어미 (verb endings).  관형사 always precedes a noun/substantive:

> 이 꽃 (this flower).

이것 is a different word - it is a pronoun (대명사), though etymologically it comes from the 관형사 이 + 명사 것 (thing).  It can also be translated as "this" in English:

> 이것은 책이다.  (This is a book).

You can see that in both of my examples, 이/이것 is translated to English "this", but there's a difference:  in the first, it is the determiner "this", and in the second, it's the pronoun "this".